# Why MongoDB crash after a simple insert?

Tags: php, mongodb

On a simple document insert, my MongoDB server sometime unexpectedly crash.
On the collection I insert this document, there's about 14 millions documents.

- MongoDB version: 2.4.9 on Debian
- php_mongo version: 1.4.5
- PHP version: 5.4.14

The code I use:

```
$data = ["type"          => "Test"];
$res = $db->test->insert($data);
```

The error I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'Couldn't get connection: Failed to connect to: 192.168.2.23:27017: Remote server has closed the connection' in C:\xx\Data.php on line 160

MongoCursorException: Couldn't get connection: Failed to connect to: 192.168.2.23:27017: Remote server has closed the connection in C:\xx\Data.php on line 160
```

The mongod log:

```
    Tue Jan 21 16:55:07.433 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.10.80:43934 #1 (1 connection now open)
    Tue Jan 21 16:55:19.995 [conn1] insert xxx.activity ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:124101 124ms
    Tue Jan 21 16:55:52.168 [conn1]  xxx.activity Deleted record list corrupted in bucket 18, link number 9, invalid link is 1788887572:6aa04074, throwing Fatal Assertion
    Tue Jan 21 16:55:52.168 [conn1]  xxx.activity Fatal Assertion 16469
    0xde46e1 0xda44d3 0xa633c8 0xa63c42 0xac91c3 0xaca5af 0x9f8a69 0x9f94d9 0x9ffd68 0x6e8518 0xdd0cae 0x7fdc1efbdb50 0x7fdc1e360a7d
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xde46e1]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi+0xa3) [0xda44d3]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo16NamespaceDetails10__stdAllocEib+0x488) [0xa633c8]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo16NamespaceDetails13allocWillBeAtEPKci+0x32) [0xa63c42]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11DataFileMgr6insertEPKcPKvibbbPb+0x1153) [0xac91c3]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11DataFileMgr16insertWithObjModEPKcRNS_7BSONObjEbb+0x4f) [0xaca5af]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo14checkAndInsertEPKcRNS_7BSONObjE+0x119) [0x9f8a69]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo14receivedInsertERNS_7MessageERNS_5CurOpE+0x929) [0x9f94d9]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo16assembleResponseERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE+0xab8) [0x9ffd68]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo16MyMessageHandler7processERNS_7MessageEPNS_21AbstractMessagingPortEPNS_9LastErrorE+0x98) [0x6e8518]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo17PortMessageServer17handleIncomingMsgEPv+0x42e) [0xdd0cae]
     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x6b50) [0x7fdc1efbdb50]
     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fdc1e360a7d]
    Tue Jan 21 16:55:52.227 [conn1]
    ***aborting after fassert() failure
    Tue Jan 21 16:55:52.228 Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
    Tue Jan 21 16:55:52.237 Backtrace:
    0xde46e1 0x6d06c9 0x7fdc1e2b84f0 0x7fdc1e2b8475 0x7fdc1e2bb6f0 0xda450e 0xa633c8 0xa63c42 0xac91c3 0xaca5af 0x9f8a69 0x9f94d9 0x9ffd68 0x6e8518 0xdd0cae 0x7fdc1efbdb50 0x7fdc1e360a7d
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xde46e1]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10abruptQuitEi+0x399) [0x6d06c9]
     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x324f0) [0x7fdc1e2b84f0]
     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x7fdc1e2b8475]
     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x180) [0x7fdc1e2bb6f0]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi+0xde) [0xda450e]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo16NamespaceDetails10__stdAllocEib+0x488) [0xa633c8]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo16NamespaceDetails13allocWillBeAtEPKci+0x32) [0xa63c42]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11DataFileMgr6insertEPKcPKvibbbPb+0x1153) [0xac91c3]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11DataFileMgr16insertWithObjModEPKcRNS_7BSONObjEbb+0x4f) [0xaca5af]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo14checkAndInsertEPKcRNS_7BSONObjE+0x119) [0x9f8a69]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo14receivedInsertERNS_7MessageERNS_5CurOpE+0x929) [0x9f94d9]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo16assembleResponseERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE+0xab8) [0x9ffd68]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo16MyMessageHandler7processERNS_7MessageEPNS_21AbstractMessagingPortEPNS_9LastErrorE+0x98) [0x6e8518]
     /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo17PortMessageServer17handleIncomingMsgEPv+0x42e) [0xdd0cae]
     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x6b50) [0x7fdc1efbdb50]
     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fdc1e360a7d]
```

On restart, mongod say:

```
     Tue Jan 21 17:04:33.521 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
    Tue Jan 21 17:04:33.521 [initandlisten] recover begin
    Tue Jan 21 17:04:33.521 [initandlisten] recover lsn: 34950
    Tue Jan 21 17:04:33.521 [initandlisten] recover /var/lib/mongodb/journal/j._0
    Tue Jan 21 17:04:33.554 [initandlisten] recover skipping application of section seq:0 < lsn:34950
    Tue Jan 21 17:04:33.944 [initandlisten] recover cleaning up
    Tue Jan 21 17:04:33.944 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
    Tue Jan 21 17:04:34.175 [initandlisten] recover done
    Tue Jan 21 17:04:34.175 [initandlisten] preallocating a journal file /var/lib/mongodb/journal/prealloc.0
    Tue Jan 21 17:04:37.065 [initandlisten]                 File Preallocator Progress: 1059061760/1073741824       98%
    Tue Jan 21 17:04:37.933 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
    Tue Jan 21 17:04:37.934 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
```

When I use the console:

```
> db.activity.insert({Type: "test"})
Tue Jan 21 17:40:10.161 Socket recv() errno:104 Connection reset by peer 127.0.0.1:27017
Tue Jan 21 17:40:10.178 SocketException: remote: 127.0.0.1:27017 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [127.0.0.1:27017]
Tue Jan 21 17:40:10.178 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Tue Jan 21 17:40:10.178 Error: error doing query: failed at src/mongo/shell/query.js:78
Tue Jan 21 17:40:10.179 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017
Tue Jan 21 17:40:10.179 reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 failed couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017
>
```

Any advice ?

Comment: can you insert from mongo console?

Comment: Indeed, when I use the console, I get quite the same error (see my post edit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the data file is broken (deleted record list corrupted). Other people seem to [have run into the same issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11862) before.

You'll probably have to use `--repair` to repair the data files. Read the [documentation on repairDatabase](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase), especially the part that explains that `--repair` will **delete corrupt data**, so make a backup if you can.

Comment: We are trying that in our dev environnement. This command is taking a while. We keep you in touch.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some problem with the data, delete everything in the mongo storage dir (if you can), restart mongo and try again.

dont forget to backup all the data before you delete it.

Comment: seriously? Your advice is to simply DELETE ALL DATA?

Comment: if it never worked, there is no data, thats why i said "if you can"

Comment: The OP states that he's got 14M documents. Also, how should the delete list be corrupt if the DB is empty?

Comment: thats why i said backup.

Comment: That won't make the data available again, either. The files must be repaired if you don't want to wade through millions of bytes with a hex viewer and `--repair` can do that.

Comment: i will never underestimate --repair, but what i said also helped me once